# String to Date Conversion in java using jacksonMapper not working

Tags: java, json, jackson

Context: Trying to convert a JSON string value into java Date value using jacksonMapper

Code:

```
MyPOJO {

  private String id;

  private String desc;

  private Date startDate;

  // getters and setters

  }
```

My Service DAO call to insert a record into DB for MyPOJO after receiving the MyPOJO as a JSON string object:

```
 MyPOJODAO {

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  mapper.setDateFormat("formatter");
  MyPOJO myPojo= mapper.reader(MyPOJO.class).readValue(myPojoJsonString);

  // db call to insert myPOJO to DB
  }
```

However, the DB call fails with an error incompatible type : found BINARY required DATE.
When I print the myPOJO before making the DAO insert call I can see the `startDate` field has failed to get converted into Date format.

What am I missing? Or easier alternatives, please?

Comment: mapper.setDateFormat(formatter);

Comment: @mavi corrected the typo

Comment: @dirai show us the json date

Comment: startDate:1466620200000

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the line:

From:
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormatter ("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

To:
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");